# Python Pickling Problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pickle

I have here some python 3 code that uses the "pickle" module. It is supposed to store high scores for a game. When I open the program again it instead gives me the default "A : 100..." high scores.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.filename = "highscores.dat"
    self.numScores = 5

    if not os.path.isfile(self.filename):
        self.file = open(self.filename, "wb")
        self.scores = [100 for i in range(self.numScores)]
        self.names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
        self.highscores = [(self.names[i], self.scores[i]) for i in range(self.numScores)]
        self.updateFile()
    else:
        file = open(self.filename, "rb")
        self.highscores = pickle.load(file)
        file.close()
        self.file = open(self.filename, "wb")

        self.names = [highscore[0] for highscore in self.highscores]
        self.scores = [highscore[1] for highscore in self.highscores]

 def addScore(self, name, score):
    self.scores.append(score) #Add new score 
    self.scores.sort(reverse = True) #Sort
    self.names.insert(self.scores.index(score), name)
    self.names = self.names[:self.numScores] # Top 5
    self.scores = self.scores[:self.numScores]
    self.highscores = [(self.names[i], self.scores[i]) for i in range(self.numScores)]
    self.updateFile()

def updateFile(self):
    pickle.dump(self.highscores, self.file)
```

This is only the parts of the code where I believe the problem to reside. I will post more if it is needed. I would be happy to answer your questions. thank you.

Comment: If you were to use a full, absolute path name, does it work then?

Comment: As in "C:\Users\Bobby\Dropbox\LD25\highscores.dat"? I just tested it, and it has the same problem.

Comment: You may want to insert a print statement in the `__init__` to see what is happening with the `.isfile()` test there. Is the file created at all?

Comment: Already thought of that. It works as intended as far as I can see.

Comment: Next test is to add a print statement to `updateFile()`, printing `self.highscores`.

Comment: Thought of that too. It works also.

Comment: @user1149589 Have you seen if your issue is in this line: `if not os.path.isfile(self.filename):` I am not sure, but I don't know if you really want the `not` there.

Comment: I do. If that file doesn't exist I run the file creation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to re-open the file for writing each time. Currently, you are writing new records each time the score changes, all one after the other, in your file. Your file now contains several pickles but only the first is being read.

Change your code to:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.filename = "highscores.dat"
    self.numScores = 5

    if not os.path.isfile(self.filename):
        self.scores = [100 for i in range(self.numScores)]
        self.names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
        self.highscores = [(self.names[i], self.scores[i]) for i in range(self.numScores)]
    else:
        with open(self.filename, "rb") as f:
            self.highscores = pickle.load(f)
        self.names = [highscore[0] for highscore in self.highscores]
        self.scores = [highscore[1] for highscore in self.highscores]

def updateFile(self):
    with open(self.filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(self.highscores, f)
```

with `addScore` unchanged.

The highscore file is now being written *from scratch* each time the score changes.

Comment: May I ask something completely different? How many years of python experience do you have?

Comment: I have to admit I am a little jealous :P

Comment: Actually reading your careers profile made me even more jealous :P I would like to thank you for sharing your knowledge with us here! It means so much to people like me who recently became enlightened!

Comment: Thanks. I can't directly copy this code due to my being in a competition that forbids such things, but I was able to write my own solution from your explanation.